# Flutter: Firebase Auth UI stuck on verification screen

Tags: flutter

I want to use the **firebase_ui_auth** package and i am testing with the example app in the repository. When i register a user with email and password the verify email screen is pushed and the issue i am facing is that after i click on the url to verify, the app remains in the loading state. I have connected the app to a firebase project, are there any other settings that I need to make?

Thanks in advance.

[image]